# Is it recommended to have separate wars for separate source trees in opengrok?

Tags: indexing, opengrok, code-search-engine

I have multiple source trees which can be grouped. Should i have a single war or multiple wars for each group? What are the benefits? Less indexing time?

Thanks,
xabhi

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate trees that could be grouped, you should probably want to use the [`ENABLE_PROJECTS`](https://github.com/cnst/OpenGrok/blob/master/OpenGrok#L219) or [`-P` (*`addProjects = true`*)](https://github.com/cnst/OpenGrok/blob/master/src/org/opensolaris/opengrok/index/Indexer.java#L165) option when indexing with [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.ru/).

This will make it possible for you (and the users of your OpenGrok) to select which projects you want to search in from a single webpage, similarly to how it's done at http://BXR.SU/.

Speed-wise, *it-depends*.   Indexing time should not change significantly, since OpenGrok already does indexing of separate projects in separate and concurrent threads.